# RadioButtons and CheckBoxes not working properly on iOS and UWP

Tags: ios, xamarin, uwp, cross-platform, xlabs

I am working on a cross platform app using `Xamarin` in `Visual Studio 2015`. I am using `XLabs.Forms v2.3.0- pre 05` and I am having problems with `radio buttons` and `checkboxes`.

Right now the `checkboxes` work fine on `UWP` but they won't show on `iOS`.

The radio buttons, on `UWP` won't work at all while on `iOS` only the texts gets displayed

See pictures below.

This is my code for checkboxes:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_ReportQuestions">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout 
                  Orientation="Vertical"
                >
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout WidthRequest="{Binding DisplayWidth}">
                      <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding ItemName}" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <controls:CheckBox DefaultText="" WidthRequest="40" IsEnabled="false" IsVisible="true" Checked="true" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

                  </StackLayout>
                  <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding SubText}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is my code for radio buttons:

```
<Label Text="Radio Buttons"/>

    <Frame
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        OutlineColor="#000000"
      >
      <controls:BindableRadioGroup x:Name="ansPicker"
                                   IsVisible="true"/>
    </Frame>

ansPicker.ItemsSource = new[]
        {
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Orange"
        };
```

I have tried to follow other possible fixes, but nothing worked for me.

[image: UWP]
[image: iOS]

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms does not define any CheckBox control or radio button. You can use a Switch that should do what you expect. or use library such as [this](https://github.com/hugoparis19/Xamarin_BemCheckBox)